# Parsing JSON string with VBScript and json2.asp

Tags: json, parsing, vbscript

I usually do not have any issues parsing and getting the values I need from JSON strings. I use json2.asp and it works great usually. I am having heck of a time getting the values from this JSON string -

{"registrantList": [{"attrList": [{"name": "Attendee Type","val": "Attendee"},{"name": "Country","val": "US"},{"name": "Attendee Status","val": "Accepted"}],"optInAttendeeSearch": false,"optInMsgTickler": false,"optInRFID": false,"optInTwitterEnrollment": false,"optInTwitterSessionAttendance": false,"additionalInfo1": "","additionalInfo2": "","additionalInfo3": "","additionalInfo4": "","additionalInfo5": "","address1": "550 Aspendale","address2": "","altPhone": "","blogUrl": "","city": "Woodland Park","country": "","county": "","customerId": "le04nd72gg1oo9iw338g","department": "","descr": "","email": "sreinhold@acme.com","facebookUrl": "","fax": "(512)555-2664","first": "Susan","fullName": "","imAccount": "","last": "Reinhold","lastModified": "2016-02-05-11.35.08.507000","linkedinUrl": "","loginId": "____","mobile": "","nickName": "","organization": "Acme","personalEmail": "","phone": "(512)555-1235","postalCode": "34753","prefix": "","region": "","id": "20160205173508517361000000","num": "le04nd72gg1oo9iw338g","title": "Event Planner","twitterAccount": "","url": ""}],"lastModified": "2016-02-05-11.35.08.507000"}

Usually I would set my variable API_Response equal to the JSON and then parse it with this Set Att = JSON.parse(API_Response). Then I can get the field I need like Response.write "CustomerID: " & Att.registrantList.get("customerId")"

But that does not show anything. Anybody have any ideas as to why?

Comment: I figured it out - Att.registrantList.get("0").get("first")

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. Need to to this - Att.registrantList.get("0").get("first")